# how to call oracle report from menu oracle 10g developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

Now I am using Oracle 10g developer But now I am facing some problem. I use this code for report running

`run_Product(REPORTS,'D:\Reports\n_sal_sheet_worker.rep', SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME,FILESYSTEM,'', NULL);`

but report not run. So pls help me. I don't know how to call oracle report from menu oracle 10g developer.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @mitun Welcome to stackoverflow, kindly provide some more info like your existing code, so that people can help you

Comment: run_Product(REPORTS,'D:\Reports\n_sal_sheet_worker_Active.rep', SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME,FILESYSTEM,'', NULL);

Comment: @Mitun From reports server log, you can trace error details, post the error if you couldn't decipher.

Comment: @Mitun You could also try to call report from browser if OC4J is started. E.g. `http://localhost:8888/reports/rwservlet?report=n_sal_sheet_worker_Active.rep&userid=userid/password@db_sid&paramform=no&destype=FILE&desname=c:\filename.pdf&desformat=pdf`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But how I use this code?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `run_product` built in is not supported in Oracle Forms 10G onwards.

The following is taken from  the Oracle White Paper "Integrating Oracle Reports in Oracle Forms Services applications" which currently can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/frm10gsrw10g-132606.pdf).

> Using RUN_PRODUCT to generate Reports output is not supported in
>   Oracle Forms 10G. Form module containing integrated calls to
>   Reports using RUN_PRODUCT Built-in won’t compile.

You should change your code to use the `run_report_object` built in.

This same document quoted above has an excellent example of how to use `run_report_object`